# Navigation Bar positioning Elements

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, hover

Hello this is the what I need to build: [Mockup](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3229/dcj752ty_jpg.htm)

I stuck at the Navigation Bar, here is the CSS:

/* CSS Document */

```
body {background:#fff url(bg.jpg) repeat-x; margin:0; padding:0; height:1800px; font-        family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#wrapper {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}

#header {height: 400px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; }
#header .logo {position: absolute; width: 374px; height: 221px; display: block; float:     left; cursor: pointer; background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent; top: 55px;     left: 10px;}
#header .contact-info {position: absolute; width: 293px; height: 133px; display: block;     float: left; cursor: pointer; background: url(contact-info.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;     top: 100px; left: 700px;}

ul.mn {
position: absolute;
float: left;
top: 316px;
width: 316px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul.mn li {
float: left;
}

ul.mn li a {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 73px;
margin-left: 6px;
}

ul.mn li a.mn1 {
width: 104px;
background-image: url('mn1.png');
background-position: 0 0;
}

ul.mn li a.mn2 {
width: 212px;
background-image: url('mn2.png');
}


ul.mn li a.active, ul.mn li a:hover {
background-position: 0 73px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RW-Fliesen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />



</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header_wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <a href="index.html" class="logo" title="Logo"></a>

        <div class="contact-info" title="contact-info"></div>

        <ul class="mn">
        <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn1 "></a></li>
        <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn2 "></a></li>
        </ul>






    </div>

</div>





</div>



</body>
</html>
```

When I have only one Navigation element looks all good: [Navi with only one element](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html)

But when I add the second Navigation Element, the Navi looks like that: [Navi with more than one element](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3229/fsx9njxj_png.htm)

How can we fix it?

Comment: I added second element to your markup and it still looks fine
after adding third element the last one appeared on below but that was only because that you have limited width on <ul> element

Comment: Thank you @MySqlError. I did it like above code and it did not work. Did you code it with a different style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are giving a width for each `li` tag.

```
ul.mn li a.mn1 {
  width: 104px;  
  background-image: url('mn1.png');
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

In the above code you have given width of 104px as the image for HOME is 104px wide. So guessing your next menu item would be having greater width which it's parent `ul` cant accommodate in one line. `ul` has a width of 316px.

```
ul.mn {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 316px;
  width: 316px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

You need to increase the width of the `ul` to make it work.

Comment: thank you @anpsmn. now it looks better, but the elements are with space between. can you tell me how to fix this? http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3229/3xvrf22j_png.htm

Comment: Remove the margin-left for `ul.mn li a`

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you were trying to mimic the mock-up site that you referenced in your initial post. I believe you should make the following adjustments to section of your css code that addresses your menu bar. What you provided:

```
ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 978px; margin: 0; padding:0; list-style-type: none; }
```

What I am proposing:

```
ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 850px; margin: 0 auto 0 10px; padding:0; list-style-type: none;}
```

Notice that I changed the width to reflect the width as dictated by the combined widths of each of your defined button divs to 850px from 978px, then I proposed that instead of setting all of the margins to 0 that you make the top 0, the right auto, bottom 0, and the left 10px (because from what I perceive from your mock-up the left side of the menu is to line up with the left side of the logo).  Making those changes I was able to get your menu bar to sit nicely at the base of your header div.

Please keep, at least me, informed on your progress.  I am always looking to share ideas and learn how other approach problems.  I believe it makes us all that much more intelligent.

Best of luck,
Steve